# Camera for product shots under #300 compatible with Adobe Photoshop

Tags: photoshop

Which camera would you recommend for product photos under $300 but compatible with Adobe Photoshop?

Comment: Any. All cameras that produce JPEGs, JPEG2000s, TIFFs, BMPs, (which means: virtually any camera).... are compatible with Photoshop, as Photoshop can read and write all these (and more) formats. This question is unclear.

Comment: Adobe lists cameras that are compatible with their Photoshop software athttps://helpx.adobe.com/camera-raw/kb/camera-raw-plug-supported-cameras.html#Supportedcameramodels   Many are not

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Shopping Question. Also, price is but one factor in choosing a camera. There are many factors - and we could help you to make an informed decision on your purchase - but we'd need to know every factor important to you. No one can suggest a camera based on price alone. Even type of photography isn't really *that* helpful.

Comment: To expand on my close vote: how big are the products? Do you have a studio? What type of vibe do you want to create (all white background style brightly lit or more dynamic with different backgrounds and colors)? Where are the images going/how will they be used? Are you opposed to used gear? What's your photo knowledge and how much do you want to learn? Have you budgeted for lighting and lenses and studio?

Comment: Hardware recommendations would be better suited...

Comment: But otherwise... get a used but warrantied DSLR or DSLM type camera with full manual control. Get a macro lens and a simple tripod and cable release. Invest the rest in LIGHTING, not camera, accessories. Full manual control means aperture, shutter speed, white balance, iso, and focus can be set manually, there is preferrably a spot metering feature, and there is a DoF preview facility if it is a DSLR. Lighting accessories: flashguns, lamps, reflectors, softboxes, wiring, filters, backgrounds, tripods, ....

Comment: ...and maybe a light tent and/or photo table.

Answer (score 4):

> Adobe lists cameras that are compatible with their Photoshop software athttps://helpx.adobe.com/camera-raw/kb/camera-raw-plug-supported-cameras.html#

You have a misunderstanding about compatibility. A type of image file that contains raw data is called a RAW file. Different brands use different extensions for their RAW files (e.g. CR2 for Canon and NEF for Nikon). [Side note: even a camera capable of shooting RAW can be set to shoot jpg instead - which will load in Photoshop right out of the camera. There are many reasons to shoot RAW that I'm not going to go into - but I highly advise you look into it]

RAW data **must** be processed to be usable. The list that you linked is for Adobe Camera Raw (RAW processing Software that is attached to Photoshop) and it lists all of the camera and file types that Adobe Camera Raw can support.

If you have a camera that can create a RAW image that is not on this list...it's probable that *that* camera also has a branded software available to interpret the RAW data.

Once the RAW data is interpreted, you will have a different file type - either a jpg, tiff, bmp, etc. All of the image file types are supported by Photoshop.

So, the answer to your question is: get any camera. If it can shoot RAW, convert with Adobe Camera Raw if available and, if not, make sure the camera maker also supplies a Raw processing software (e.g. Canon supplies Digital Photo Pro to convert their RAW files).

Comment: IMHO, given the question, the OP's current photography knowledge is well below what is required to use raw files properly. If it's to only use defaults then the jpegs from the camera with proper settings will be just as good.

Comment: @xenoid I agree. I should have linked the how to shoot products with a phone question.

Comment: Actually, Windows 10 onboard tools can view some raw files natively. And disastrously.